# How to use the physical location of rows (ROWID) in a DELETE statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, rowid

I have a table that has a lot of duplicated rows and no primary key.
I want to remove just the duplicated records, but when I try to do this it would remove all peers.

How can I find the `ROWID` from a table in Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On PostgreSQL the physical location of the row is called CTID.

So if you want to view it use a QUERY like this:

```
SELECT CTID FROM table_name
```

To use it on a DELETE statement to remove the duplicated records use it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE CTID NOT IN (
  SELECT RECID FROM 
    (SELECT MIN(CTID) AS RECID, other_columns 
      FROM table_name GROUP BY other_columns) 
  a);
```

Remember that table_name is the desired table and other_columns are the columns that you want to use to filter that.

Ie:

```
DELETE FROM user_department WHERE CTID NOT IN (
  SELECT RECID FROM 
    (SELECT MIN(CTID) AS RECID, ud.user_id, ud.department_id
      FROM user_department ud GROUP BY ud.user_id, ud.department_id) 
  a);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simplify this by one query level:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE  ctid NOT IN (
   SELECT min(ctid)
   FROM   table_name
   GROUP  BY $other_columns);
```

.. where duplicates are defined by equality in `$other_columns`.
There is no need to include columns from the `GROUP BY` clause in the `SELECT` list, so you don't need another subquery.

[`ctid` in the current manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `row_number()` if want to delete based on a unique id column(or a timestamp), since `ctid` alone is not always reliable when you want to only keep recent records etc.

```
WITH d 
     AS (SELECT ctid c, 
                row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY s 
                    ORDER BY id) rn 
         FROM   t) 
DELETE FROM t 
WHERE  ctid IN (SELECT c 
               FROM   d 
               WHERE  rn > 1)  ;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=619d215d2b7b4b804f136f8c55067b79)