# SQL syntax error while deleting record from temp table

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to SQL. I tried to delete the duplicate customer record where has same name and surname. This below is my command

```
delete duplicated_records from  (
  select row_number() over (partition by name, surname
                            order by name, surname) as rn
      ,          * 
  from customer
) duplicated_records where rn > 1;
```

Which throw me this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "duplicated_records"
LINE 1: delete duplicated_records from  (
```

But when I tested running just to see the record, I didn't get any error.

```
select duplicated_records from  (
  select row_number() over (partition by name, surname
                            order by name, surname) as rn
      ,          *
  from customer
) duplicated_records where rn > 1;
```

Could anyone please advise me if I did something wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your syntax: _DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition;_

Comment: @iLuvLogix in this case, could you please guide me what's I should change my command to? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL Removing duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928704/postgresql-removing-duplicates)