# How to use delete clause after with clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

Query 1:

```
with table1 as (select * from table2) delete * from table1;
```

Query 2:

```
with table1 as (select * from table2) delete * from table1 where col1 = 'something';
```

Both of the above query are returning error after execution? Can someone help me here?

Comment: You can't delete from the result of a query. Query 1 can be replaced with `delete from table2` and query 2 can be replaced with `delete from table2 where col1 = 'something'` - but I assume that's not what you actual underlying problem is. What exactly are you trying to do? Please provide some sample data and the expected results

Comment: i am trying to delete duplicate rows using row_number as following:                      with rohilla as (select row_number() over(partition by fruit order by fruit) row_num, fruit from rk) delete from rohilla where row_num >1;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+[duplicates]+delete

Comment: the problem is i do not have identifier on my table, so can you post sol for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier

Comment: If you don't have a Primary Key (*identifier*), your table is meaningless anyway. [BTW: there always is a ctid]

Comment: Please post your table schema and logic of identifying duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the problem statement in the comment section, you can use the query below to delete duplicates

```
delete from rohilla a using rohilla b where a=b and a.ctid < b.ctid;
```

Using with clause you can do the following to delete duplicates. (Col1 below can be any column, if entire row is duplicated)

```
WITH x AS 
( 
         SELECT   col1, 
                  Min(ctid) AS min 
         FROM     rohilla 
         GROUP BY col1
         HAVING   Count(col1) > 1 ) 
DELETE 
FROM   rohilla b 
using  x 
WHERE  x.col1 = b.col1
AND    x.min <> b.ctid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete from a CTE in Postgres.  Clearly, I'm sure you are aware that you can do:

```
delete from table2
    where col1 = 'something';
```

If you want to involve a CTE, then you can use some sort of filtering, typically on a primary key:

```
with table1 as (
      select * from table2
     )
delete from table2 t2 using
     table1 t1
     where t1.<primary key> = t2.<primary key> and
           t1.col1 = 'something';
```

Comment: what does CTE mean?

Comment: @RahulKumar . . . "Common Table Expression".