# Postgres - add sequential column to existing data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table that currently doesn't have an id column and a lot of duplicate rows on what should be a unique pair - it's messy. Example:

```
 fips  | customer_id
-------+------------
 17043 |        2085
 17043 |        2085
 42091 |        4426
 42091 |        4426
```

customer_id/fips should be unique, but the current code and schema don't enforce that. There also isn't an id column, so I have no unique way to reference a single row.

I'd like to add an id column and assign sequential integers so I can have a unique primary key. How can I go about that?

Comment: Please, always disclose your Postgres version (`SELECT version();`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres 10 added `IDENTITY` columns (as demonstrated in [Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69146858/939860)).
In Postgres 9.6 (or any version) you can use use a `serial` column instead.

Either way, make it the `PRIMARY KEY` in the same command. That's cheaper for big tables:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN tbl_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

Or:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN tbl_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=90594b278caf7d690fc047ad434ce436)*

`IDENTITY` columns are **not** `PRIMARY KEY` automatically. Postgres allows multiple `IDENTITY` columns for the same table (even if that's rarely useful).

See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

**Or** you clean up the mess to make `(fips, customer_id)` unique. Then that can be your PK. See:

- [How to delete duplicate rows without unique identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769454/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-without-unique-identifier/26773018#26773018)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an identity column:

```
alter table t add column id int generated always as identity;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=38d9229a7472fe13d2036e34a56c9b37) is a db<>fiddle.